# Serres "Linear representation of finite groups", problem with understanding a corollary in chapter 2

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

In Serre chapter two we have as the second corollary of Schur´s Lemma that if we got a linear representation of $G$ and $(x_{i_1 i_2})$ is the matrix of a linear map from an irreducible representation $V_1$ to an irreducible representation $V_2$. Then:

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{t\in G}r_{i_2 j_2}(t^{-1})r_{j_1 i_1}(t) = 0 $$.

What is used in the proof is that if we let t run through $G$:

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{t, i_2, j_2}r_{i_2 j_2}(t^{-1})x_{j_2 j_1} r_{j_1 i_1}(t) = 0~~~~~~(*)$$

The argument in the book is the following:
The right hand side of the equation (*) is a linear form with respect to $x_{j_2 j_1}$ and that this is true, because this form vanishes for all values of the $x_{j_2 j_1}$ its coefficients are zero. It is not mentioned what linear form this is. What is the domain and how does the mapping work?

Comment: I do not understand you fist sentence

Comment: What exactly does not make sense in my first sentence?

Comment: No I don't understand the sentence. What does the first corollary say? "If we got a linear representation and ...." then what?

Comment: Oh then the second equation is true.

Comment: I changed the comment to make it more clear

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. Just noticed that the first sum only runs through t. I changed the comment again.

Comment: Are talking about corollary 1 in the book?

Comment: Corollary 2 in chapter 2.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. I took the liberty to edit your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_1$ have dimension $m$ and $V_2$ have dimension $n$. Then all that's claimed is that the map

$$T_{i_2i_1}\colon\mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}$$

given by

$$T_{i_2i_i}\colon (x_{j_2j_1})\mapsto\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{t,j_1, j_2}r_{i_2j_2}(t^{-1})x_{j_2j_1}r_{j_1i_1}(t)$$

is a linear map. This is clear. By Corollary 1 of Chapter 2, we know that if $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are not isomorphic, then your equation (*) will always hold for any set of numbers $\{x_{j_2j_1}\}$ that is the right size to be the entries of an $m\times n$ matrix, which means that $T_{i_2i_1}$ is the zero linear transformation. The matrix of $T_{i_2i_1}$ corresponding to the obvious basis of matrices with 1s in one entry and zeroes everywhere else is an $mn\times 1$ matrix (a row vector, if you prefer) whose entries are precisely the numbers

$$\frac{1}{|G}\sum_{t\in G} r_{i_2j_2}(t^{-1})r_{j_1i_1}(t)$$.

Therefore all these numbers are zero. This holds for every pair of indices $i_2, i_1$.

Comment: I dont quite understand why $T$ is a linear map or what map it is. You rather described it as a map from a matrix entry to that averaging 
sum of the entry that has that index, or am I missing something?

Comment: @FlynnFehre The map $T$ takes a matrix to a complex number. I write $(x_{i_2i_1})$ for the matrix whose entries are  $x_{i_2i_1}$ as $i_2$ and $i_1$ vary.

Comment: Dawydiak But it maps it to the complex number where also the indices $i_1, i_2$ vary? Or do you map it to the number for arbitrary indices?

Comment: I have added further explanation. If you are still confused, I suggest that you just read the proof in Serre's book.